# ¿Cómo escribir una ruta al archivo en cmd con -F "file=@/...."?

Tags: windows, cmd

Tengo que ecribir la ruta al archivo en CMD, Windows 10. El archivo deseado está en mi desktop y tengo el ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```
-F "file=@/path/to/the/file.xlsx"
```

Pero nosé si esto será lo correcto:

```
-F "file=@/c:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/int.xlsx"
```

Y si hay alguna otra forma más corta de hacerlo.

Comment: si mueves el archivo a `C:` la ruta será más corta ;) * kidding *

Comment: :D buena respuesta. Pero es correcta la forma en la que lo he escrito con `file=@/`?

Comment: No lo se, estoy mirando. No se si es errata al hacer la pregunta, pero te falta cerrar comillas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el problema utilizando lo que puse en mi pregunta:

```
-F "file=@/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/int.xlsx"
```

El `%USERPROFILE%` por alguna razón me trae el error:

> la ruta del archivo no ha sido reconocida

Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Esta directiva debería funcionar en windows:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\int.xlsx
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero %USERPROFILE% no me funciona. Me dice que no lo reconozca, pero ya he encontrado la solution. Saludos.

Comment: @Lukas Podrías escribir una respuesta con la solución que te ha servido y marcarla como correcta en un día, podría ayudar a más gente con tu mismo problema.

Comment: He escrito la solución... no optimiza la longitud del código y es la solución que estaba en mi pregunta, por eso he estado esperando más opciones, pero bueno, eso funciona, ya lo he puesto.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
-F "file=@%USERPROFILE%/Desktop/int.xlsx"
```

Ten en cuenta que cada usuario tiene las carpetas de sistema configuradas a su gusto, y no tienen porqué estar en C:\Users. Con la variable de entorno `%USERPROFILE%` te aseguras coger la ruta donde la tiene configurada el usuario.

Parece que sobraba la primea barra. **Prueba con esto ahora.**

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero %USERPROFILE% no me funciona. Me dice que no lo reconozca, pero ya he encontrado la solution. Saludos.